# Insert into MySQL db occurs twice in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm currently building a small site to retrieve player stats for a computer game from a mysql db and display them online.

I get player statistics for a list of players from a third party API and am trying to insert them into a table in the db. However my code is performing the inserts twice - the primary key restriction on the table stops duplicate entries, but I don't want to accept this.

Something is amiss with my looping logic, but I'm going in my own loop trying to figure this one out.

Sequence of events is:

1. I query my db to get the player ID's needed for the API calls
2. I put these in an array
3. I query the third party api in a loop to get all the player stats
4. I want to insert the stats (1 row per player) to my db (I plan to escape the strings etc, it's a work in progress)

   ```
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $member_data[] = $row;
   }

   foreach ($member_data as $id) {

   $endpoint =  "http://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/Stats/2/".$id[destiny_membership_id]."/".$id[destiny_character_id]."/";

   $bungie_result = hitBungie($endpoint);
   $response = json_decode($bungie_result, true);

   $destiny_membership_id = $id[destiny_membership_id];
   $destiny_character_id = $id[destiny_character_id];
   $kills_deaths_ratio = $response[Response][allPvP][allTime][killsDeathsRatio][basic][displayValue];

   // DB insert
   $sql = "INSERT INTO xax_pvp_stats (destiny_membership_id,destiny_character_id,kills_deaths_ratio) ";
   $sql .= "VALUES ('$destiny_membership_id','$destiny_character_id','$kills_deaths_ratio') ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
       echo "<br />Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . $conn->error;
   } else {
       echo $destiny_character_id." is in the DB";
   }
   }

   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }
   ```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `$response[Response][allPvP][allTime][killsDeathsRatio][basic][displayValue]` <-- that should've given you all sorts of errors, and you're calling `$conn->query($sql);` twice (`$result = $conn->query($sql);` + `if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE)`)

Comment: Thanks Jay - I'm going to sort that, it's still in early stages at the minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the query twice.  Once here:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

and once here:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
```

I'm guessing you meant to examine the *result* in the second line:

```
if ($result === FALSE) {
```

Comment: Couldn't see the wood for the trees! Thanks, a definite blonde moment

Comment: @LukeWallwin: It happens :)  Glad we could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

Several issues, starting with the one you're worried about (insert happening twice):

1) You're calling `$conn->query` twice, which, of course, executes the `INSERT` query twice:

Here:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);//insert1

if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {//insert 2
    echo "<br />Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . $conn->error;
} else {
    echo $destiny_character_id." is in the DB";
}
```

2) Your code is vulnerable to injection, learn about prepared statements and use them

3) accessing values in an associative array requires the keys to be quoted: `$response[Response][allPvP][allTime][killsDeathsRatio][basic][displayValue]` issues notices. When developing, always use `display_errors`, and set the error level as strict as you can `E_STRICT|E_ALL` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks Elias, I'll look to incorporate all of this!

Answer (score 0):

You're running the query twice: once when you set $result then again in the following if statement. Remove the $result line (you're not using that variable anyway) and you'll be good to go.